# When did neurotransmitters derived from monoamines first appear in evolutionary history?

Tags: neuroscience, evolution

- When did [neurotransmitters derived from monoamines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoamine_neurotransmitter) first appear in evolutionary history?
- What are main the points in evolution for monoamines based on the neurotransmitter system ?

**Edition**

I'm interested in this area because, there is far less monoamines neurotransmitters  based neurones than based on amino acid neurotransmitters. So it seems that monoamines based system is fine tuning work of the whole system while, amino acid neurotransmitters based neurons are the work hourse.

Comment: Just curious, the [wikipedia entry on the evolution of monoamine neurotransmitters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoamine_neurotransmitter#Evolution) links to this article; is it useful? Lövheim, Hugo (2012). "A new three-dimensional model for emotions and monoamine neurotransmitters". Medical Hypotheses 78 (2): 341–8. doi:10.1016/j.mehy.2011.11.016. PMID 22153577.

Comment: An interesting question.  Some type of receptor-mediated membrane potential regulation probably can be found in single-cell eukaryotes, but I don't have a reference for that.

Comment: @Chuck Sherrington interesting thanks

Comment: This might be more appropriate for biology.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for Biology.SE